# Using self-defined Cython code from other Cython code

Tags: python, class, methods, composition, cython

I am currently trying to optimize my Python program and got started with Cython in order to reduce the function calling overhead and perhaps later on include optimized C-libraries functions.

So I ran into the first problem:

I am using composition in my code to create a larger class. So far I have gotten one of my Python classes converted to Cython (which was difficult enough). Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
ctypedef np.float64_t dtype_t
ctypedef np.complex128_t cplxtype_t
ctypedef Py_ssize_t index_t

cdef class bendingForcesClass(object):
    cdef dtype_t bendingRigidity
    cdef np.ndarray matrixPrefactor
    cdef np.ndarray bendingForces

    def __init__(self, dtype_t bendingRigidity, np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] waveNumbersNorm):
        self.bendingRigidity = bendingRigidity
        self.matrixPrefactor = -self.bendingRigidity * waveNumbersNorm ** 2

    cpdef np.ndarray calculate(self, np.ndarray membraneHeight):
        cdef np.ndarray bendingForces
        bendingForces = self.matrixPrefactor * membraneHeight
        return bendingForces
```

From my composed Python/Cython class I am calling the class-method `calculate`, so that in my composed class I have the following (reduced) code:

```
from bendingForcesClass import bendingForcesClass

cdef class membraneClass(object):
    def  __init__(self, systemSideLength, lowerCutoffLength, bendingRigidity):
        self.bendingForces = bendingForcesClass(bendingRigidity, self.waveNumbers.norm)

    def calculateForces(self, heightR):
        return self.bendingForces.calculate(heightR)
```

I have found out that `cpdef` makes the method/functions callable from Python and Cython, which is great and works, as long as I don't try to define the type of `self.bendingForces` beforehand - which according to [the documentation (Early Binding For Speed)](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EarlyBindingForSpeed) is necessary in order to remove the function-calling overhead. I have tried the following, which does not work:

```
from bendingForcesClass import bendingForcesClass
from bendingForcesClass cimport bendingForcesClass

    cdef class membraneClass(object):
        cdef bendingForcesClass bendingForces

        def  __init__(self, systemSideLength, lowerCutoffLength, bendingRigidity):
            self.bendingForces = bendingForcesClass(bendingRigidity, self.waveNumbers.norm)

        def calculateForces(self, heightR):
            return self.bendingForces.calculate(heightR)
```

With this I get this error, when trying to build `membraneClass.pyx` with Cython:

```
membraneClass.pyx:18:6: 'bendingForcesClass' is not a type identifier
building 'membraneClass' extension
```

Note that the declarations are in two separate files, which makes this more difficult.

So I how do I get this done? I would be very thankful if someone could give me a pointer, as I can't find any information about this, besides the link given above.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: I'd like to see what the problem is, so keep us posted if something works out!

Comment: I realize this is an old question but I am having a very similar problem right now. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. Unfortunately I never solved this problem, since at some point this part of code became irrelevant for my project. Anyway I wish you good luck, and if you figure it out, post it here and I'd be happy to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: After lot of searching, I found this perfect answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616927/cython-using-imported-class-in-a-type-declaration

Answer (score 7):

*Disclaimer:* This question is very old and I am not sure the current solution would work for 2011 Cython code.

In order to cimport an extension class (cdef class) from another file you need to provide a [.pxd](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html) file (also known as a definitions file) declaring all C classes, attributes and methods. See [Sharing Extension Types](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-extension-types) in the documentation for reference.

For your example, you would need a file `bendingForcesClass.pxd`, which declares the class you want to share, as well as all cimports, module level variables, typedefs, etc.:

bendingForcesClass **.pxd**

```
# cimports
cimport numpy as np

# typedefy you want to share
ctypedef np.float64_t dtype_t
ctypedef np.complex128_t cplxtype_t
ctypedef Py_ssize_t index_t

cdef class bendingForcesClass:
    # declare C attributes
    cdef dtype_t bendingRigidity
    cdef np.ndarray matrixPrefactor
    cdef np.ndarray bendingForces

    # declare C functions
    cpdef np.ndarray calculate(self, np.ndarray membraneHeight)

    # note that __init__ is missing, it is not a C (cdef) function
```

All imports, variables, and attributes that now are declared in the `.pxd` file can (and have to be) removed from the `.pyx` file:

bendingForcesClass **.pyx**

```
import numpy as np

cdef class bendingForcesClass(object):

    def __init__(self, dtype_t bendingRigidity, np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] waveNumbersNorm):
        self.bendingRigidity = bendingRigidity
        self.matrixPrefactor = -self.bendingRigidity * waveNumbersNorm ** 2

    cpdef np.ndarray calculate(self, np.ndarray membraneHeight):
        cdef np.ndarray bendingForces
        bendingForces = self.matrixPrefactor * membraneHeight
        return bendingForces
```

Now your cdef class `bendingForcesClass` can be cimported from other Cython modules, making it a valid type identifier, which should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a declaration ".pxd" file and cimport. (Essentially, cimport happens at compile time, while import happens at run time so Cython can't make use of anything important).

> Create "utils.pxd":

```
cdef class MyClass:
    cdef readonly int field
    cdef void go(self, int i)
```

> "utils.pyx" now reads

```
cdef class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, field):
    self.field = field

cdef void go(self, int i):
    self.field = i
```

all declarations which have been in the pyx file go into the .pxd file.

> Then in mymodule.pyx

```
from utils import MyClass
from utils cimport MyClass
# other code follows...
```

// Extended answer from here:
[Cython: using imported class in a type declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616927/cython-using-imported-class-in-a-type-declaration)

Answer (score 2):

These are probably not the source of the error, but just to narrow down the problem, you might try to change the following:

Could it be that you are using `bendingForces` as the name of the variable here:

```
cpdef np.ndarray calculate( self, np.ndarray membraneHeight ) :
      cdef np.ndarray bendingForces
      bendingForces = self.matrixPrefactor * membraneHeight
      return bendingForces
```

and also the name of the member object here:

```
cdef class membraneClass( object ):
    cdef bendingForcesClass bendingForces
```

Also, `bendingForcesClass` is the name of the module as well as the class. Finally, how about making a `ctypedef` from the class `bendingForcesClass`?

Comment: due to editing the original question to use PEP8, this answer is slightly out of sync; sorry about that.