# Cython: using imported class in a type declaration

Tags: python, cython

I'm writing a Cython 0.23 program, and I can't figure out how to use a `cdef class` that I import from a different module in a type declaration. Here is a snippet that reproduces the problem.

`test.py`:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()

from mymodule import *

obj = MyClass(42)
print(obj.field)
print(identity(obj).field)
```

---

This works as expected and prints `42` twice:

`mymodule.pyx`:

```
cdef class MyClass:
    cdef readonly int field
    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field

cpdef MyClass identity(MyClass obj):
    return obj
```

---

This fails with a compiler error:

`mymodule.pyx`:

```
from utils import MyClass

cpdef MyClass identity(MyClass obj):
    return obj
```

`utils.pyx`:

```
cdef class MyClass:
    cdef readonly int field
    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field
```

---

The error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from utils import MyClass

cpdef MyClass identity(MyClass obj):
     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

mymodule.pyx:3:6: 'MyClass' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from utils import MyClass

cpdef MyClass identity(MyClass obj):
                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The project I need this for is small and I can refactor it so that I don't need to import the class, but this solution doesn't look very clean. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to [use a declaration ".pxd" file](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html) and `cimport`. (Essentially, `cimport` happens at compile time, while `import` happens at run time so Cython can't make use of anything imported).

Create "utils.pxd":

```
cdef class MyClass:
    cdef readonly int field
```

"utils.pyx" now reads

```
cdef class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, field):
    self.field = field
```

(i.e. remove the declaration of `field` since it's specified in the .pxd file).

Then in `mymodule.pyx`

```
from utils cimport MyClass
# other code follows...
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to keep the class definition in one place?

Comment: I don't think so (and I agree - this is a bit of a hassle with this method).

Comment: @DavidW - From the docs here - https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html do we need cdef cppclass now ? I obviously will ask my own question because I am getting the same compilation error

Comment: `cdef cppclass` is used when wrapping classes defined in c++. `cdef class` defines a class you can use from Python but with Cython type definitions, so they do different things. In both cases they can be cimported to use them in another Cython module.